# Call to a member function log() on a non-object

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, programmatically

I wrote code like this...

```
<?php
class SmashingMagazine_LogProductUpdate_Model_Observer
{
    public function logUpdate(varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $name=$product->getName();
        $sku=$product->getSku();
        magic_quotes_runtime()->log ("{$name} ({$sku}) updated", null, 'product-updates.log');
    }
}
```

And this is the error which I got. 
Fatal error: Call to a member function log() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\SmashingMagazine\LogProductUpdate\Model\Observer.php on line 9.
Help me.

Comment: I figured it out. 
In specified line, I had typed mage() and my IDE typed it as magic_quotes_runtime() and I failed to oversee it, then I deleted -> and put double colons (::) and bingo!! :)

Answer (score 4):

`magic_quotes_runtime()` is a function and not an object ;)

Use: `Mage::log("your log string");` instead.

Comment: yeah, my IDE typed that automatically and I didn't check it.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni :o *Incompetence*